# how to convert a csv file of time.series data with multiple sensors?

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning, csv

I want to convert a CSV file of uct time-series (iso8601) data with multiple sensors. This is what the raw data currently looks like:

[image: current data]

The different sensors are described by names (Client column) and have a different values of axes.

This is the way I would like the data to be:

[image: desired output]

PS: the Time Measured may be different between the sensors and there is a synchronization phase to be done(classification of time Measured every 200 ms).

Any ideas/hints to solve this problem?
I am fairly new to programming, especially Python, so I have already run out of ideas.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

here an example, you can adapt to your use case with a fake input :

### Full code

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("input.csv")
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"])

dsensor1 = df[df["Client"]=="sensor1"]
dsensor2 = df[df["Client"]=="sensor2"]

dout = pd.merge_asof(dsensor1,dsensor2, on="time", tolerance=pd.Timedelta(value=200,unit="milli"), direction="nearest")
```

### Code explanation

As received time can be different you can't use usual pandas function to
merge dataFrame. You have to use an *asof merge* base on the time
column (time values must be sorted). The pandas function to do that is
[`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html#pandas.merge_asof).

Let's take a fake input.csv file

|  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **time** | **Client** | **val** |
| 12:50:27.724 | sensor1 | 1 |
| 12:50:27.809 | sensor2 | 5 |
| 12:50:28.824 | sensor1 | 2 |
| 12:50:28.924 | sensor2 | 8 |

Table 1: Fake input.csv

Here I assume that ',' is the field separator in the input.csv file.
Then we need to tell to Pandas that the "time" column is a time type. In
order to do that I use the `to_datetime` function.

```py
df = pd.read_csv("input.csv")
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["time"])
```

|  | time | Client | val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-06-27 12:50:27.724000 | sensor1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-06-27 12:50:27.809000 | sensor2 | 5 |
| 2 | 2021-06-27 12:50:28.824000 | sensor1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2021-06-27 12:50:28.924000 | sensor2 | 8 |

Then we extract two separate dataframes from sensors1 and from sensors2

```py
dsensor1 = df[df["Client"]=="sensor1"]
dsensor2 = df[df["Client"]=="sensor2"]
```

Here for sensor1, dsensor1 is:

|  | time | Client | val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-06-27 12:50:27.724000 | sensor1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-06-27 12:50:28.824000 | sensor1 | 2 |

Then we just have to do the soft merge between the two dataframes with a
tolerance of 200ms. The *direction* argument means that pandas will join
the lines whose *time values* are the closest within the *tolerance*
range.

```py
dout = pd.merge_asof(dsensor1,dsensor2, on="time", tolerance=pd.Timedelta(value=200,unit="milli"), direction="nearest")
```

|  | time | Client<sub>x</sub> | val<sub>x</sub> | Client<sub>y</sub> | val<sub>y</sub> |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-06-27 12:50:27.724000 | sensor1 | 1 | sensor2 | 5 |
| 1 | 2021-06-27 12:50:28.824000 | sensor1 | 2 | sensor2 | 8 |

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I need